# Adding 2 values in a Batch PHP file

Tags: php, cacti

Below code works great with getting only a bunch IP address and add it to Cacti `--description='".$dev."' --ip='".$dev."'`, now I want to add bunch of IP with their description in cacti forexample(`--description='".$hostname."' --ip='".$dev."'`).
I am newbie to PHP and don't know how to add 2 values instead of 1 value in PHP.

**devices.txt**

```
1.1.1.1
```

**add_device_bulk.php**

```
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
       $line = chop($line);
       print "[".$line."] \n";
       createHost($line);
    }
} else { 
    die("Could not open file $filename!"); 
}

die;
    
function createHost($dev)
{
    global $community;
    global $hosttemplate;
    print "================== Creating Node & Graph for $dev =======================\n";
        
    $ret = cmd("/usr/bin/php add_device.php --quiet --description='".$dev."' --ip='".$dev."' --template=$hosttemplate --community='".$community."' --avail=snmp ");
    //Get host id from: [RET] Success - new device-id: (20)
    if (preg_match("/\((\d+)\)/", $ret, $matches))
    {
        $deviceID =  $matches[1];
        print "Device ID: $deviceID \n";
        //We got a device - create graphs for device
        $ret = cmd("/usr/bin/php add_graphs.php --graph-type=ds --graph-template-id=5 --host-id=".$deviceID." --snmp-query-id=1 --snmp-query-type-id=10 --snmp-field=ifOperStatus --snmp-value-regex=Up --snmp-field=ifDescr --snmp-value-regex='GigabitEthernet'");
        
        //RET: Graph Added - graph-id: (34) - data-source-ids: (37, 37)
        if (preg_match("/\((\d+)\)/", $ret, $matches)) {
             $graphID =  $matches[1];
        
             //We got a graph - add it to default tree
             # cmd("/usr/bin/php /cacti/appl/cacti/cli/add_tree.php  --type=node  --node-type=graph --tree-id=1 --graph-id=".$graphID);
         }
     }
}

function cmd($cmd)
{
    print "[CMD] $cmd\n";
    $ret =  exec($cmd)."\n";
    print "[RET] $ret\n";
    return $ret;
}
```

Now I want to add description instead of IP and have a text file as below:

**devices.txt**

```
Link1, 1.1.1.1
```